# How to stack divs beside each other to create a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a carousel, where clicking on any element will slide it leftwards, simultaneously sliding the right element into viewport. For that, I need to have the `div`s stacked side by side. I am trying it out as a `float` based layout (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cupidvogel/nf5Dh/) ).

Problem is that here clicking the red colored `div` slides it leftward alright, but not the green element leftwards. This is probably due to the fact that they are actually lying below another, as visible when the `overflow: hidden` is removed from `#cont`'s style. How elese to stack them side by side so that sliding one leftward automatically slides the next one leftwards as well? (Creating the to-be-next element on the fly while clicking and animating it into viewport is a no-no, the element should be present in the DOM!)

Comment: I can help you with the the next to each other div thing with [google charts example](http://jsfiddle.net/JSwth/). The key part of my example is the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a plugin, as there is more to this than you may realize. There are many plugins out there for this, here's a list to get you started: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

I modified your Javascript, HTML, and CSS to get you pointed in the right direction:
http://jsfiddle.net/nf5Dh/2/

You need a container `contContent`, positioned absolutely, and that container gets moved within the container div. You just float the elements in `contContent` to get them next to each other.

HTML:

```
<div id='cont'>
    <div id="contContent">
        <div id='i1'></div>
        <div id='i2'></div>
        <div id='i3'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cont {
  width: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#contContent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#contContent > div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
#i1 { background: red; }
#i2 { background: green; }
#i3 { background: yellow; }
```

And the JS:

```
$("#contContent > div").click(function(){
    $("#contContent").animate({left: "-=50px"},1000);
});
```

You'd probably be better off using an `ul` instead of all divs, this is at least more semantically correct, though not technically necessary.

```
<div id="carousel">
    <ul id="carouselContent">
        <li id="slide1"></li>
        <li id="slide2"></li>
        <li id="slide3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#cont {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pane { // or whatever the slide divs are called. get rid of the float.
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
```

Comment: The `HTML`, please? I can't make anything of it!

Comment: You can't expect people to write everything for you, that's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: #cont #platform .pane .pane .pane /#platform /#cont --
animate the #platform.

Comment: @sellmeadog, Yeah I know pretty well that people are not going to write everything for me. But if someone asks for a layout solution, and a guy answers it with two barebone stylesets without describing where they apply, how thy apply, even Eric Meyer would have a hard time getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that carousel where you can generate javascript for the carousel http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/configuration-robot.php

Comment: No, I need to do considerable customization, so I can't depend on a 3rd party application...

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ for things like this in the past, that's based on postion: relative and left/right offsets. Probably easier than messing with floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a list item instead, and display them inline.